# Probability of exponential distribution less than normal distribution.

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

$X$ is the exponential distribution $e^{-x}$, $Y$ is the normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $1$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent. How do I find $P(X<Y+1)$?

My attempt:
$$\int_{-1}^{\infty} F_X(y+1) f_Y(y)    dy$$
$$=\int_{-1}^{\infty} (1-e^{-(y+1)}) f_Y(y)    dy$$
$$=\phi(1)-\int_{-1}^{\infty} (e^{-(y+1)}) f_Y(y)    dy$$

Am I on the right track? How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You should mention $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Where does the $\lambda$ come from? You started out correctly.

Comment: @StubbornAtom My bad there's no lambda.

Comment: @Code He just removed it! xD

Comment: SImply add and remove $3$ to complete the square, then change variable and get again an integral of a normal!

Comment: This should be similar to $\phi(1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac 3 2}\phi(2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\phi(1)-\int_{-1}^{\infty} (e^{-(y+1)}) f_Y(y)    dy $$

$$ = \phi(1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(y^2+2y+2)}dy$$

$$ =  \phi(1)-\frac{e^{-\frac 1 2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}t^2}  dt $$
where $t=y+1$.

$$ = \phi(1) - \frac{e^{-\frac 1 2}}{2}$$